# Send SMS "TO" Twillio from Forms

Tags: forms, sms

I currently have a Webhook setup in Twilio and its functioning correctly. I text my Twilio number a name and the service receives the text and send the name to a screen that I have connected at the house.

I want guests to be able to interact with the screen and "send" their own names to the screen as well, but I dont want them to have the number, because they can leave the house, and continue sending text to the screen.

I tried Google forms, but it tries to use Twilio to send a message to the person who responded to the form. I need the persons response in the form to be sent to Twilio, so the webhook can than pick it up and send it to my screen.

I was going to setup a QR Code that they can scan and it would take them to the Google Form. that QR code would have a built in re-direct, so that if the same IP address scanned the QR Code again, they would be re-direced to my FB page instead of the google form.

Any tips on how to set something up to be able to feed info to Twilio base don the info I provided?

I tried the Google form, but again, I was only able to send the SMS to the Respondant, and not to Twilio.

I can use the Twilio number and it works just fine, but I need some way to mask that number from the respondent.